# Formatação para número de casas decimais dinamicamente utilizando Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, formatação

```
import math

def formating_pi(n):
    a= "pi com {:c} casas decimais é {:.17}"
    return a.format(n, math.pi)

formating_pi(5)
```

Gostaria de não colocar o número `17` explicitamente, mas sim o resultado da expressão `n + 1`.

No entanto, quando tento fazer isso, o seguinte erro é levantado:

> ```
> ValueError: Format specifier missing precision.
> ```

Porque o `n` ou `n + 1` não são vistos como um números.

Neste caso `n` é 5 o que é suposto de alguma forma resultar com output `pi` com 5 casas decimais é `3.14159`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma opção é criar a string de formatação dinamicamente e depois utilizá-la em conjunto com o método `format`.

Mais ou menos assim:

```
n = 17
fmt_str = f"{{:.{n + 1}}}"

print(fmt_str)  # {:.18}
```

Note que utilizei dois colchetes de abertura e fechamento (`{{` e `}}`) para que o Python não os utilize para interpolação (ainda).

Uma vez que a string de formatação tenha sido criada dinamicamente (algo, no exemplo acima, como `"{:.18}"`, podemos passá-la para o método `format`.

```
import math

n = 17
fmt_str = f"{{:.{n + 1}}}"

print(fmt_str)  # {:.18}

result = fmt_str.format(math.pi)

print(result)  # 3.14159265358979312
```

Comment: Muito obrigada pela resposta super rápida Luiz.

Comment: @UgaBuga Na minha resposta tem uma opção para não precisar somar 1 ao `n` :-)

Answer (score 3):

No [`format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) é possível fazer assim:

```
import math

def formating_pi(n):
    fmt = "pi com {} casas decimais é {:.{size}f}"
    return fmt.format(n, math.pi, size=n)

print(formating_pi(5)) # pi com 5 casas decimais é 3.14159
```

Não esqueça de colocar o `f` para indicar que se trata de um `float` (assim não precisa somar 1 ao `n`).

Veja na [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec) todas as opções de formatação. Com *f-string* ficaria assim:

```
def formating_pi(n):
    return f"pi com {n} casas decimais é {math.pi:.{n}f}"
```

---

Se bem que, para arredondar para uma determinada quantidade de casas decimais, pode usar [`round()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round):

```
import math

def formating_pi(n):
    fmt = "pi com {} casas decimais é {}"
    return fmt.format(n, round(math.pi, n))

print(formating_pi(5)) # pi com 5 casas decimais é 3.14159
```

Ou, com *f-string*:

```
def formating_pi(n):
    return f"pi com {n} casas decimais é {round(math.pi, n)}"
```

Comment: E eu reinventando a roda! Bom saber. :-)

Comment: @LuizFelipe Ainda bem que ["*There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it*"](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/), né?  :-)